# Are there working open source implementations of the Kalman filter to correct accelerometer data?

Tags: objective-c, c, kalman-filter

Are there working open source implementations of the Kalman filter in C or Objective-C to correct accelerometer data?

I couldn't find one, but before I start spending a month on this I'd better ask :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not that I know of. But don't you want Kalman filter to remove **gyro drift**? That's what it is good for.

Kalman filter is difficult to understand. If you do not understand it you won't be able to implement and use it correctly.

The good news is that you have other filters with comparable results, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586658/combine-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-data/1590385#1590385) helpful. See especially the [filter.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaLVJLSkRwMTU0b0E).

If you insist on the Kalman filter, the most human readable intro with examples I have found so far is the [SIGGRAPH Course Pack](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf).

Comment: A guy with a huge, heavy brain told me that the Kalman filter is the best thing in the universe for this kind of stuff. :-)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, Kalman filter is good. Kalman filter is optimal when some presumed conditions are met. That is you cannot do better when ceratin conditions are met. But those conditions are often not met in practice and Kalman filter is just an ad-hoc method then (SIGGRAPH Course pack, p. 25). I think it is better to have a filter you understand than having one you don't understand and misuse that. Good luck!

Comment: @Ali Will you be able to give me alternative way to kalman filter to smooth gps data? Can I get the implementation of it in Objective C?

Comment: @ViruMax Unfortunately no. I haven't done any programming in Objective C. I could only search for an implementation myself too, sorry.