# Sensor Fusion on iOS Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, compass-geolocation, gyroscope

I'm trying to find out how could I start to implement sensor fusion on the iPhone. I've started from this talk from David Sachs:

[Sensor Fusion on Android Devices](http://talkminer.com/viewtalk.jsp?videoid=C7JQ7Rpwn2k&q=)

Although David's talk is very illustrative, it doesn't show any code (it makes sense). I've seen both the [GLGravity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLGravity/Introduction/Intro.html) (to extract the gravity vector) and the [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) examples, but I need some help or at least guidance on how to combine the accelerometer, gyroscope and compass inputs so that the result is similar to what David shows.

Thanks

Comment: hi how were you able to do it can you explain that ?

Comment: Hi, I finally used the compass alone, but the response from @Ali is the best I could find.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of May 19, 2015, there is no point in implementing sensor fusion yourself on mobile devices: Both Android ([SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) under `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`) and iPhone ([Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAttitude) under `CMAttitude`) offers its own.

---

---

*(The original answer from May 5, 2011)*

I have implemented sensor fusion for [Shimmer 2](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions) devices based on this [manuscript](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA). I highly recommend it.

Sensor fusion is often achieved by [Kalman Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586658/341970).

However, there is no such thing as *"Kalman Filter for programmers"*. Kalman filter is difficult to understand. You won't be able to implement and use it correctly if you do not understand it. Just use the above manuscript.

Comment: Your last link is broken.

Comment: @confile Thanks for the notice. It is not broken: That question was unfortunately deleted. However, you can still read it if you have enough reputation. Anyway, thanks, I will revise my answer so that it does not contain links that are not accessible to everyone.

Comment: Could you please link some code where Kalman Filter was done in iOS?

Comment: @confile I just did, hope this helps.

Comment: Are these libraries suitable for sensor fusion of other kinds of data, like RSSI or audio loudness?

Comment: @PetrusTheron No, unfortunately not out of the box. You would have to then implement it yourself, sorry.