# Android How to bring app to foreground if the condition meets

Tags: android, service

I want to bring my application to front if the cell phone has a speed more than 70 km /hour.
It already runs in background as a service. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the above steps:

1. In the service you will have to detect the speed of the phone using accelerometer. See [Using accelerometer to calculate speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921395/using-accelerometer-to-calculate-speeds) and there are many other questions to answer this part.
2. When you detect the speed going above 70 km/hr, open the home activity of the app using `Intent`. See [android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

You may have to include a check that if the activity has been started once, when the speed went over 70km/hr, it should be started again and again for the same ocassion.

This is my 2 cents for your problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.... Though i would love if you tell me how to go to any other xml instead of home activity directly. Thanks again.

Comment: Just start that particular activity instead of Home one.

Comment: tried it. but does not work for any other activity else than mainActivity :(