# Gyroscope drift on mobile phones

Tags: mobile, gyroscope

Lots of posts talk about the gyro drift problem. Some guys say that the gyro reading has drift, however others say the integration has drift.

1. The raw gyro reading has drift[[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586658/combine-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-data).
2. The integration has drift[[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246256/gyro-sensor-drift-and-correct-angle-estimation)(Answer1).

So, I conduct one experiment. The next two figures are what I got. The following figure shows that gyro reading doesn't drift at all, but has the offset. Because of the offset, the integration is horrible. So it seems that the integration is the drift, is it?
[image]

The next figure shows that when the offset is reduced the integration doesn't drift at all.
[image]

In addition, I conducted another experiment. First, I put the mobile phone stationary on the desk for about 10s. Then rotated it to the left then restore to back. Then right and back. The following figure tells the angle quite well. What I used is only reducing the offset then take the integration.

[image]

So, my big problem here is that maybe the offset is the essence of the gyro drift(integration drift)? Can complimentary filter or kalman filter be applied to remove the gyro drift in this condition?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the gyro reading has "drift", it is called **bias** and not drift.

The drift is due to the integration and it occurs even if the bias is exactly zero. The drift is because you are accumulating the white noise of the reading by integration.

For **drift cancellation**, I highly recommend the [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) manuscript, I have implemented sensor fusion for [Shimmer 2](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions) devices based on it.

(Edit: The document is from the [MatrixPilot](https://github.com/MatrixPilot/MatrixPilot) project, which has since moved to Github, and can be found in the Downloads section of the wiki there.)

If you insist on the Kalman filter then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5478881/341970.

**By why are you implementing your own sensor fusion algorithm?**

Both Android ([SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) under `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`) and iPhone ([Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAttitude)) offers its own.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks! Actually, I'm know little about the white noise, I seems that the white noise has minor effect on the integration from the third diagram, is it? So is the drift really a serious issue?

Comment: Yes, the error can become arbirarily large due to the white noise. Of cource, if you have bias, the situation is even worse :( Anyway, upvoted your question!

Comment: Appreciated :) I really want to see the the error due to the white noise to get some sense of how to calibrate it. Should I collect the gyro data in 1 hour or others?

Comment: @AllenJee If you collect the data for an 1 hour, you will see that the bias is fluctuating. Otherwise, I recommend the Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory manuscript, it will give you a clear understanding of the issue. It's basically a tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: For Android, `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` does not seem to be implemented on all devices (on the OnePlus One running Cyanogenmod I never got any events). There's also the deprecated `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` as well as API functions to calculate roll, pitch and yaw from accelerometer and magnetometer readings. However, my experience after trying to get yaw values from both sensors on two different devices is that accuracy is somewhere between mediocre and horrible, depending on the device.

Comment: @Ali, I've been trying to understand your statement on drift because of white noise. By drift, I mean gyro integrated output monotonically increasing or increasing when gyro is at rest. If the noise in the gyro output (due to thermo vibrations) is true white noise, then by definition it was zero mean. When you integrate this, you get random walk noise, which also has zero mean. So the gyro integrated output has time-increasing variance, but can't really drift when at rest - am I missing anything?

Comment: @EzequielGarcia I am afraid I do not follow. *"When you integrate this, you get random walk noise, which also has zero mean."* No, the expected value of the translation distance is monotonically increasing, see [Gaussian random walk on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Gaussian_random_walk). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Ali, see my reply below.

Comment: Does android sensor manager and ios core motion also somehow actively use magnetometer data?

Comment: @lolelo In theory, they could *if* the device has a magnetometer, and that may help to reduce the drift. However, don't expect a miracle from the magnetometer readings. I cannot tell you what the sensor manager or the core motion internally does, sorry.

Comment: @Ali So `CMAttitude` (the class that you linked above) for iPhone is actually offering a fusion of acc and gyro sensors?

Comment: @Bendemann Yes, that is the case. You don't have to do the sensor fusion yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The dear Ali wrote something that is really questionable and imprecise (wrong).

The drift *is* the integration of the bias. It is the visible "effect" of bias when you integrate. The noise - any kind of stationary noise - that has mean zero, consequently has integral zero (I am not talking of the integral of PSD,  but of the additive noise of the signal integrated in time).

The  bias changes in time, as a function of voltage and exercise temperature. E.g. if voltage changes (and it changes), bias changes. The bias it is not fixed nor "predictable".
That is why you can not eliminate bias using the proposed subtraction of the estimated bias by the signal. Also any estimate has an error. This error cumulates in time. If the error is lower, the effects of cumulation (the drifting) become visible in a longer interval, but it still exists.

Theory says that a total elimination of bias it is not possible, at the present days. At the state of the art, no one has still found a way to eliminate the bias - based only gyroscopes and accelerometers magnetometers - that could filter all the bias out.

Android and iPhone have *limited* implementations of bias elimination algorithms. They are not totally free by bias effects (e.g. in small intervals). For some applications this can cause severe problems and unpredictable results.

Comment: "The noise - any kind of stationary noise - that has mean zero, consequently has integral zero." Are you familiar with the concept of [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)? Or to put it in another way, if you toss a coin 100 times, according to your logic, I get exactly 50 heads and 50 tails. Do you see the problem? I suggest you revise your answer.

Comment: He probably meant that the mean value of the integral is zero, too. Drift is a systematic tendency in a process. I am no expert in this, but I do not see any way to compensate for the integrated noise. The integrated bias, on the other hand, could be cancelled by on-the-fly recalibration based on detection of prolonged periods of near-zero angular acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

In this discussion both Ali and Stefano have raised two fundamental aspects of drifts due to ideal integration.

Basically zero mean white noise is an idealized concept and even for such ideal noise integration offer higher gain over lower frequency component of noise, which introduces a low frequency drift in the integrated signal. By theory the zero mean noise should not cause any drift iff observed over significantly long time but practically ideal integration never works.

On the other hand, even a minor dc-offset in the reading (input signal) can cause a significant drift over a time, if an ideal integration (loss-less summation) is performed on it. It can ramp up a very small dc-offsets in the system, as ideal integration has infinite gain on DC component of an input signal. Therefore for the practical purpose we substitute ideal integration by a low pass filter whose cut-off can be as low as required but can not be zero or too low for practical purpose.

Comment: *"By theory the zero mean noise should not cause any drift iff observed over significantly long time"*  Are you familiar with the concept of [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)? I suggest you revise your answer.

Comment: I agree there will be a fluctuation like random walk but if the noise is "really" a zero mean noise and if we observe for long enough time duration ideally till infinity the integrated signal should show equal amount fluctuation over zero. However, no simulated random noise is ideal zero mean noise, so in practice or even in simulation I can expect some drift (Liked Ezequiel's simulation). Over a short time scale we can see the signal drifting but over long enough time scale obviously it will fluctuate across zero rather being drifting away from zero continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by Ali reply (thanks Ali!), I did some reading and some numerical experiments and decided to post my own reply about the nature of gyro drift.

I've written a simple [octave online script](http://octave-online.net/?s=ZKBoHkaGpBaHXnEtEgyHDyKRCIdbEdpKuMnVwzHGGaOiMhmX) plotting white noise and integrated white noise:

[image]

The angle plot with reduced offset that is shown in the question seems to resemble a typical random walk. Mathematical random walks has zero mean value, so that cannot be accounted as drift. However, I believe numerical integration of white noise leads to non-zero mean (as can be seen in the histogram plot for random walk below). This, together with linearly increasing variance could be associated to the so-called gyro drift.

There is a great introduction to errors arising from gyroscopes and accelerometers [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-696.pdf). In any case, I still have much to learn, so I could be wrong.

Regarding the complimentary filter, there's some discussion [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220508155901/http://pieter-jan.com/node/11), showing how the gyro drift is reduced by it. The article is very informal, but I found it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The term gyro drift is loosely used to describe the gyro bias which causes a drift in the integral. There are various error types on a gyro measurement. Most commonly, we talk about noise and bias. Noise is almost always assumed white noise (unless you are actually working on a gyro design at which point this answer is moot). Bias can have a constant term (constant during a single power-up, not life-time) and a (mostly unpredictably) moving bias (sometimes called instability).

Kalman Filter can be used to estimate and remove some of the bias. This amount relies on the noise, bias instability and measurement quality. KF will also (try to) fix your angle errors.

Complementary filter is used to remove the drift from the integral, rather than  to estimate the sensor errors.

---

I would like to expand on the previous answers and fix some of the misleading statements.

Ali has stated that (I am paraphrasing) "due to the integration of white noise, the expected angle error increases". This is not accurate. Assuming we have a 1-dimensional rotation problem at hand, the expected error due the integration of the white noise is 0 (expected value = mean). However, it's standard deviation indeed walks monotonically. An important distinction without which Kalman Filter would not work. Stefano is right.

Note that I specified a 1-dimension restriction. 3-D is a different beast, but the 0 expected value should still apply.

The issue with the bias entirely depends on your sensors. Low quality sensors tend to have "bias drift" or "bias stability" (instability or whatever you would like to call it). That is, the bias value changes over time (due to various reasons) and this change is rather significant both in terms of its magnitude and the speed of the change. Very high quality sensors, on the other hand, try to minimize this so that we have a constant bias (as the dominating term). This is easier to estimate and correct during run time.

Note that any gyroscope that you can get your hands on is a low quality sensor. Such that we don't even mention the rotation of the Earth (about 15.04 deg/h).