# Android Filtered Accelerometer+Gyroscope display information

Tags: java, android, filter, accelerometer, gyroscope

The goal of my project is to come up with a tool to measure and count when the device moves up and down on a Y Axis. Say the phone was sitting on pulley system, and everytime it moves up a distance, say 1 foot, and back down I want to count that as 1 repetition. Or even get to the point where the movement is displayed on a graph.

My research so far has pointed me to a few conclusions:
The accelerometer is noisy and I need to filter whatever data I receieve from it.
I need to use the gyroscope in conjuction with the acclerometer.
The Complementary filter is an easier way  smooth the data from the sensors.
I need to get orientation of the sensor (based on gravity?) before the sensor can begin "listening" for repetitions.

So from my understanding, first I need to get orientation. next, have the sensor listen for movement. Then store the data, filter it to get an oscillating pattern, apply it to a peak detection algorithm and store the results.

I refered to this link to get information reagerding complementary filters: http://web.mit.edu/first/segway/#misc
From this post: 
[Combine Gyroscope and Accelerometer Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586658/combine-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-data)

This was very helpful in terms of getting an idea of how to put it together.

Does anyone have any code that is similar to my project? I am having a hard time even getting started with the code.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

This has been built into the Android API since version 2.3. Use `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` instead of `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`:

```
Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER = Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION + Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY
```

When using sensor fusion (`Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is a result of sensor fusion), Android uses all the sensors available to get the best possible accelerometer readings without gravity.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k&feature=results_main&playnext=1&list=PL29AD66D8C4372129