# Is the iPhone accelerometer calibrated? Gravity measurement changes depending on orientation

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, gravity, calibration

I'm doing some test with iPhone 4S accelerometer. If I take the raw data in Z-axis (telephone rest over desktop) I get an acceleration 9.65-9.70 m/s2 (after g conversion by 9.8261).
But if i have the telephone resting over edge, the measurement of the accelerometer value in the X-axis is so different, aprox. 9.80-9.85 m/s2 (after the same g conversion).
My question is, if the gravity is the same, why this difference? It is not callibrated?

On the other hand, I check the module value at both situations and the difference is the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of answer you expect, but you should be more precise when you're talking about calibration.

Of course, the g-sensors are calibrated and as always: every calibration comes with an error. In your case the error is under 1%.

So if you want an answer:

**Yes, the iPhone accelerometer is calibrated and has an error under 1% in your case.** If you collect measurements from other (hundreds of) users, you could calculate the mean error of the device (I guess it's about 1% though).

Comment: ok, I forget calibration question. More directly, why gravity measurement (module value) varies depending on the device orientation? (from 9.7 to 9.85 m/s2 when the gravity is always the same). In a Chipworks image seems the XY axis have some relationship while Z is independent (http://www.chipworks.com/uploadedimages/Technical_Competitive_Analysis/Teardowns/iPhone4/accelerometer-ST-b.jpg)
Sorry if I am wanting something too technical. Thanks

Comment: The sensor is only calibrated ~1% error for each axis. Each axis has it's own output and error rate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's not possible to determine gravity 100% exactly when all of the sensors (gyro and compass as well) show an intrinsic error. The lack of a precise external reference system leads to this error. Accelerometer and gyroscope are corrected mutually and if there is a slight drift it does affect the direction where the sensor fusion algorithm (Kalman-Filter or others) calculates gravity should be.

While gyroscope is very fast in detecting the direction it tends to drifting effects. Accelerometers are slower in reaction but provide a way to detect gravity. Magnetometers are even slower but can contribute to stabilising the overall result. [Combine Gyroscope and Accelerometer Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586658/combine-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-data) shows some graphs of the raw and the processed sensor data.

Answer (score 0):

I continued working with accelerometers. The results are not bad. About iPhone accelerometers calibrating, I can say that STMicroelectronics does calibration over his own sensor. Later, iPhone factory assemblies accelerometer onto circuit board. The soldering affects to accelerometer accuracy (thermal effects) and probably, the accelerometer requires a new calibration, but for consumer requirements, the accuracy is already good, but if you need high requirements, you need a new calibration.